# Android app doesn't want to connect to WCF Rest Service via phone 3G network

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf, rest

Good day,

I would like to know if someone can help me out. I've been struggling with this the past three days.
I've got a WCF REST service running on a small server at my house, all the needed ports are forwarded on  the router, and the service works fine when connecting from the WIFI, or external 3G dongle, but when I try to connect through the cellphone's 3G it doesn't pick it up.

The application I'm currently developing needs to be able to connect through the use of the phone's 3G network.

Please if anyone can help me out that would be great.

Thank You.

Below is the WCF Rest Service Contract, and the android application's code where I connect to the server.

WCF REST Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IAttendexService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    bool LoginUser(User user);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    Register CreateRegister(Register register);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    Register ViewRegister(int registerID);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    Register EditRegister(Register register);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    StudentRegister AttendStudent(string studentTag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    bool EmailRegister(StudentRegister studentRegister);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    List<Venue> RetrieveVenueList();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    List<Subject> RetrieveSubjectList();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    void Disconnect(string sessionKey);
}
```

Android Application Connection Code

```
public class NetworkClient
{
    private String url;
    private NetworkPacketFormatType packetFormatType;
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpPost postMethod;    

    public String ExecutePostMethod(String methodName, String jsonObjectString)
    {
       try
       {
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 25000);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String fullUrl = url + "/" + methodName;
        postMethod = new HttpPost(fullUrl);

        if (packetFormatType == NetworkPacketFormatType.JSON)
        {
            postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            StringEntity sEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObjectString, "UTF-8");
            postMethod.setEntity(sEntity);
        }
        else if (packetFormatType == NetworkPacketFormatType.XML)
        {
            // TODO: What should happen when the format type is XML.
            // TODO: Finish this.
            postMethod.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
            postMethod.addHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");

            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", jsonObjectString));

            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // TODO: What should happen to the returned json string data.
            sb.append(line);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Do something with the exception.
        return null;
    }

}
```

Lastly an example where I call this NetworkClient class

```
public void btnLoginClick(View v)
{
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Logging In");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while being authorized...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            boolean loggedIn = false;
            boolean serverOnline = false;
            EditText edtUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
            EditText edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

            // If statement to check if the loginUser object is not null.
            if (!edtUsername.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                    && !edtPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                User loginUser = new User(edtUsername.getText().toString(),
                        edtPassword.getText().toString());

                //TODO: Call the GET LoginUser method from the server.
                try
                {
                    String jsonUser = JsonBuilder.CreateJsonString(loginUser, "user");

                    // Retrieving Host Address and Port from resources,
                    // Creating NetworkClient Object.
                    String hostAddress = getResources().getString(R.string.hostAddress);
                    NetworkClient client = new NetworkClient(hostAddress, NetworkPacketFormatType.JSON);
                    String result = client.ExecutePostMethod("LoginUser", jsonUser);

                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        // TODO: Could not connect to the server.
                        System.out.println("Could not connect to server.");
                        serverOnline = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggedIn = Boolean.parseBoolean(result);
                        serverOnline = true;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO: What to do with the exception.
                }

                // If statement to check if user exists on the server,
                // then log the user into the application.
                if (loggedIn && serverOnline)
                {
                    // Creating the main intent, starting the activity and finishing the login activity.
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
                else if (!loggedIn && serverOnline)
                {
                    BasicInformationDialog dialogBox = new BasicInformationDialog();
                    dialogBox.setTitle("Error - Invalid Fields");
                    dialogBox.setMessage("Username and/or Password fields are invalid. " +
                            "Please make sure your details are correct.");
                    dialogBox.setIconId(R.drawable.defaultDialogIcon);
                    dialogBox.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogBox");
                }
                else
                {
                    BasicInformationDialog dialogBox = new BasicInformationDialog();
                    dialogBox.setTitle("Server Error: Offline");
                    dialogBox.setMessage("Could not connect to server.\n" +
                            "Please contact the administrator.");
                    dialogBox.setIconId(R.drawable.defaultDialogIcon);
                    dialogBox.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogBox");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                BasicInformationDialog dialogBox = new BasicInformationDialog();
                dialogBox.setTitle("Error - Fields Empty");
                dialogBox.setMessage("Username and/or Password fields cannot be empty. " +
                        "Please make sure your details are filled in.");
                dialogBox.setIconId(R.drawable.defaultDialogIcon);
                dialogBox.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogBox");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            if (progressDialog != null)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: The fact that it works fine on WiFi but not on cellular network suggests that there's probably something wrong with your network configuration and not the code. I'm guessing it doesn't have anything to do with WiFi or 3G. It could be failing because when you connect to it using your home network the router performs a loopback. Are you sure your ISP allows [public] port forwarding?

Comment: Yes I've checked it out, and I've connected my tablet onto another wifi spot which doesn't have access to my home network. So I guess the problem is with the Service Provider of the 3G network. Because on some phones it works through the cellphone's 3G network. But thanks was just wondering if the code is correct.